# How can you build detokenization of data coming into Salesforce via a custom API integration?

Tags: api, integration, encryption, shield, mulesoft

**Background:**

We are building an API integration fully custom between Salesforce and an internal resource to return PII data onto our Case record on page load.  The internal resource will return tokenized data to Salesforce, and our goal here is to detokenize the data.  We are having a really tough time finding resources on how we can detokenize within Salesforce not using 3rd party IPAAS tools.

**Response Considerations:**

1. We cannot store or transit the data in Salesforce - Salesforce Shield is off the table!  We are only building for the data loading on Case page load from the internal resource.
2. The tokenization pattern is TBD, let me know if that is a determining factor and I'll respond in comments.
3. We have talked to Mulesoft and are considering using them, but I want to exhaust my options here.
4. We have found resources from Salesforce [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_tokenized_sending1.htm&type=5) and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_commercepayments_tokenization_service_intro.htm), but both mention Marketing Cloud and Commerce cloud respectively and did not seem to help.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean tokenization/de-tokenization with an example?